# Facebook meta tag author not working

Tags: html, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have this:

```
<meta property="article:publisher" content="LINK_TO_FACEBOOK_FANPAGE">
<meta name="author" content="My Name">
```

But it suddenly stopped working and names are not showing anymore. I'm **not** using meta tag `article:author`, since not all of our colleagues have facebook profile. I remember like 1 month ago it worked well, but I noticed this change today. Did facebook remove it on purpose? If so, is it possible to override it, so it will show peoples' names even without facebook profiles?

Answer (score 0):

Try debugging via [Facebook Debugger](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/sharing/batch/)

Comment: I get "No Issues" in batch invalidator. And from sharing debugger "Here are the input properties that were not seen in the parsed result: 'og:locale:locale, fb:app_id, fb:admins, og:site_name, article:publisher'" but nothing about meta tag `author`

Comment: May I know the URL of your site?

Comment: Hmm... Sorry, I don't know the answer. I guess the problem is with Facebook. They haven't been appearing on my pages for a while now and I haven't seen them in other pages either. What happens if you put the name (not FB link) on `article:author` tag?

Comment: Yea I tried, nothing shown up. I need to go now, I will come online again tomorrow.

Comment: @debute, any luck with this issue?

Comment: @vitozev unfortunately not so we had to use their FB_IDs