# Facebook stopped displaying article:author

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

It looks like Facebook changed something in the last few days, I noticed the article:author information doesn't show up anymore (article:publisher still works)

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/opengraph/object-type/article

It used to be working fine like this:

```
<meta property="article:author" content="https://www.facebook.com/yovav"/>
```

For example, if you share https://ufotoday.com/post/10061 on Facebook it should show the author.

**UPDATE 2**
It is working now, I was able to add Confirmed Publications in Linked Publications after I added my facebook website pages under a company and updated the company pages in General - Category to be "News & Media Website · Publisher".

**UPDATE 1**: so Linked Publications is found in the user profile settings (and not in the company facebook page settings), first I could not find website on the facebook autocomplete list, I changed page template to "business" and set "News & Media Website", "Publisher" in category. and now it is added as Confirmed Publications.

My meta data has these values now:

```
<meta property="article:author" content="https://facebook.com/yovav" />
<meta property="article:publisher" content="https://www.facebook.com/1677453589249352" />
```

However, I still cannot see the author name next to the publisher website (in the bottom left corner of facebook posts), What am I missing here?

Comment: Perfect! This helped me. I had just noticed that my shares no longer had my name.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It appears that authors need to give permission to a publication or website (and specifically the FB page of that site) in order to be cited as the author in Facebook's byline feature.

As such, the *authors* needs to login to their own Facebook profile, go to Settings (for their own profile), and then click "Linked Publications" (Or just send them to this link: https://www.facebook.com/settings?tab=author_publisher )

There, they need to add the publication's (or site's) Facebook page as a "linked publication."

When I did this on my personal profile, I finally got back the byline functionality, both in the tag debugger and in actual Facebook posts.

However, I sent this info to all of our authors, and some of them do not have the particular setting page mentioned above. So YMMV.

Comment: Thanks, this is now getting closer, but still can't get it to work, please see my UPDATE in the question

Comment: Yes, it appears that this is still being rolled out or trialed by Facebook. Right now it only works for some people. In my organization there were some who didn't even have that settings page yet. Others had the setting, but like you still didn't have their byline show up. Still others it worked completely. The only other thing to check that can make a difference is whether you allow everybody to follow you. (That's in the privacy seeing page IIRC.) If you don't, you won't show up in bylines. However, as I said, it still might not work for you yet, and Facebook hasn't publicly addressed this.

Comment: Hey, can you please try to share this link in your facebook and tell me if you see the author... https://ufotoday.com/post/10061

Comment: No. The author still isn't listed. It appears we will have to wait for official word from FB on this, or for them to finish rolling out this change.

Comment: @Yovav you probably need to clear the Facebook share cache. You can force this on the sharer debug page: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/sharing/

Comment: Although missing author attribution in FB posts is sometimes fixed by clearing the cache (sometimes even requiring multiple attempts) , this particular problem is unaffected by clearing the cache.

Comment: This is not a cache issue

Comment: I can't see `Linked Publications` tab in settings. I am a normal facebook user. Do I need to be a verified author or something?

Comment: It is working now, I was able to add Confirmed Publications in Linked Publications after I added my facebook website pages under a company and updated the company pages in General - Category to be "News & Media Website · Publisher".

Answer (score 0):

Some people said, if you're a **Media Fanpage admin** and you already confirmed your domain by **Link Ownership** function (Only verified page have this function), you can get author back by the new function **Linked Publications**.

When you finished these things, you'll see your byline back. But...

Only you(admin) can see that. Other user still can't see this byline link.

I don't know what Facebook are doing, damn it.

[image]
[image]

Comment: LInked Publications at the bottom of setting.

Comment: Link Ownership only "Verified Media Pages" will received function invitation from Facebook.

Comment: I don't have these options, but that would not work anyways because my website has different authors, so it needs to show their individual facebook page (each article can have a different author)

Comment: Unfortunately, looks like multiple author byline is unavailable now. Maybe caused by the "Content Farm" abused this function.